# Percentage price set field error

Tags: civievent, percentage-price-field

We recently installed the Percentage Price Field extension and are using it for an event. It's working fine, but at the bottom of the Event Info page, under the fee section, this error is showing:
ERROR: percentagepricesetfield_NFMbsQAQVpVZkamC (Hint: Is the Percentage Price Set Field extension enabled?)

The error shows in the public-facing pages - I see it when I am not logged in.

We are using the Percentage Price Set Field 1.5.0, with CiviCRM 5.31.0 and WordPress.

Any suggestions to resolve this error and/or make it not show?

Comment: You ever solve this problem? I am experiencing this on Joomla with the same versions of Civi and the extension

Comment: No, we're still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Just curious: Do you happen to be using the iATS Payments or CiviDiscount extension on your site? I think there might be a database conflict with another extension